# Arranging buttons programmatically with constraints

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have an array of buttons that I am iterating through and adding the buttons onto the view. Each button should be adjacent to the previous button, so I'm setting the leading constraint to the previous button's trailing. But the buttons end up layered on top of each other with only the top one displayed.

```
for k in 0 ..< buttons.count {

    view.addSubview(buttons[k])

    if k > 0 {
        buttons[k].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttons[k-1].trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

I don't know if this is part of the problem, but here's how I'm creating the buttons. I set each to (0,0) because I don't know where they'll end up. I assume the constraint would reposition them as needed (first time use programmatic constraints).

```
let size = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: size)
```

Comment: What about using a stackview? I assume that it would make it much easier...

Comment: @AhmadF The same thing was happening when I created a horizontal stack view and added the buttons to it.

Comment: You need to code using constraints or setting the frame, not both; If you are using constraints then you will need to set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and set sufficient constraints so that the top, left, width and height of each button can be determined.  A button has an intrinsic width and height based on its content, but you will need to constrain the leading or trailing and top or bottom at a minimum

Comment: @Paulw11 So, when I set up the button, all I really need is "button = UIButton()" without the frame, then code ALL coordinates and sizes with the constraints?

Comment: Yes.  You do need `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a simple playground that works with a `UIStackView`. You can play a bit and accommodate for your goal.

`UIStackView`s are very flexible components if you want avoid creating constraints manually.

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let buttons = createButtons()
        let stackView = createStackView(with: UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical)

        buttons.forEach { button in
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }

        view.addSubview(stackView)

        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        self.view = view
    }

    func createStackView(with layout: UILayoutConstraintAxis) -> UIStackView {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = layout
        stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stackView.spacing = 0
        return stackView
    }

    func createButtons() -> [UIButton] {
        var buttons = [UIButton]()
        for x in 0..<5 {
            let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
            button.backgroundColor = .red
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            button.setTitle("Title \(x)", for: .normal)
            buttons.append(button)
        }
        return buttons
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Comment: What if I want to set button.width, height to relative size of screensize (view.frame.size)? As put that in loadView() will return with 0.0 width and height because it is not created yet. Please comment, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The key problem is you should use `isActive` to active constraint.
The following is example

```
var buttons: [UIButton] = []
for index in 0...5 {
    let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("button \(index)", for: .normal)
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    buttons.append(button)
}

for index in 0...5 {
    let button = buttons[index]
    if index == 0 {
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
    } else {
        let preButton = buttons[index - 1]
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: preButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: preButton.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    }
}
```